# Java: using setter of a subclass when creating an object of type Superclass

Tags: java, subclass, getter-setter, superclass

I have a superclass Person and two subclasses Man and Woman

in subclass Man, I have an instance variable age:

```
public class Man extends Person{

   private double age;

   public final static double MIN_AGE = 0.0;
   public final static double MAX_AGE = 65.0;

  //no argument constructor
  public Man(){
    super();
    initAge();  // This randomly selects age
  }

   /* Setters and getters */
   public void setAge (double ageIn) 
   {
      /* Assign a value only if it is within the allowed range */
      if (ageIn>= MIN_AGE && ageIn<= MAX_AGE )
      {
        this.age = ageIn;
      }
      else if (ageIn< MIN_AGE)
      {
        this.age = MIN_AGE;
      }
      else if (ageIn > MAX_AGE)
      {
        this.age = MAX_AGE;
      }
   }

  public double getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }
}
```

Now, my task is to create a Man object and test whether the setter works and whether initAge works by showing the value of "age: with getAge.

I also have to initialize the object using the following:

```
Person p1 = new Man();
```

However, if initialized this way, I do not have access to Man's setters and getters. Is there a way around this other than doing:

```
Man p1 = new Man();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `p1` to `Man`:

```
((Man) p1).setAge(13);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add abstract methods to the Person class:

```
public abstract class Person {

    public abstract double getAge();
    public abstract setAge(double ageIn);
}
```

Or, if the methods are sex-independent, move them to the parent, so Man and Woman can inherit.

Comment: Thank you. A good idea but I must not change the superclass. Thanks for the help, anyways!

Comment: In this case, if you are SURE the reference is a Man object, the only thing you can do is to use a cast.

`if (p1 instanceof Man)
    ((Man) p1).setAge(42);`

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use `Person p1 = new Man();` because that's the only way if you really do not want to create a Man object of an instantiated `new Man()`.

Now in order to access the setters and getters as a Person, you would need to mask that by casting the Man type over it.

`((Man) p1).setAge(double)`